# Angle between vectors of the form $(\cos A,\cos B,\cos C)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vector-spaces

The question:

Two vectors $S=(\cos A,\cos B,\cos C)$, $S'=(\cos A',\cos B',\cos C')$, What is the angle between them?

The answer is $\cos(\theta)$ = $\cos A.\cos A'+ \cos B.\cos B'+ \cos C.\cos C'$.

Where does this answer come from??

It seems the two vectors are not unit vectors.

Comment: It comes from the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Answer (score 1):

If you are given no restrictions on the values of $A, B, C, A', B', C'$, then I would agree that the answer they give is incorrect. It needs to be divided by the length of the vectors $(\cos A, \cos B, \cos C)$ and $(\cos A', \cos B', \cos C')$. As you say, if they are not unit vectors then there is a problem with their answer.

Perhaps there is some further information somewhere about the possible values of $A, B, C, A', B', C'$?

Comment: Thank you. There's no further infomation so I am pretty confused. It's actually from Theoretical Physics By Georg Joos. Exercise 5.

Comment: I am sure the book is wrong. Maybe he missed out the words "unit vectors" in the question, or made a typo in the answers. If we take $A, B, \dots$ all to be zero, then the lengths of the two vectors is $\sqrt{3}$ and the given answer is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $cos(\theta)= \frac{\langle{a,b}\rangle}{|a||b|}$

What do you get?